# export namespace function is undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have a namespace.

```
var ns = ns || {};
ns.test = function(){

    //stuff
    var f = function(){
    };

    return {f:f};

}
```

If i want to call `f` for example in `main.js` it says `ns is undefined`

If i change the code to this :

```
 var ns = ns || {};
export default ns.test = function(){

    //stuff
    var f = function(){
    };

    return {f:f};

}
```

The error is : `Cannot read property 'f' of undefined`

Comment: I think it is better to use a namespace for ns.test like this: ns.test = (function() { })()

Comment: You should not use namespace objects in ES6 at all.

Comment: Also show us your `main.js` file, as that seems to be where the error lies.

Comment: @Bergi ok i didnt know this, do you have a link for an equivalent example?

Comment: @lolio: Just do `export function test() { …`

Comment: @Bergi alright, i will rewrite it, thx

Answer (score 0):

`ns.test().f()` will work for you.

```
var ns = ns || {};
ns.test = function(){
    //stuff
    var f = function(){
        console.log('f invoked');
    };

    return {f:f};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var ns = ns || {};
export default ns.test = function(){

    f : function(){
  }


}
```

Call should be this way:

```
ns.test().f();
```